# How to fit Negative Binomial on count data in R

Tags: r, optimization

I want to fit Negative Binomial function on the data of
pathogen counts(x) which measured in different volumes (v) of 
water samples. I wrote some codes but they don't work properly. 
thanks for any helps.

```
x<-c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L)

v<-c(48, 51, 52, 54.9, 55, 55, 55, 57, 59, 59, 85.2, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100.4, 100.4, 100.6, 100.7, 101.7, 102, 102, 
102.2, 102.2, 103.3, 185.4, 189.3, 189.3, 190, 191.4, 18.4, 74.1, 
99.9, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 101.1, 101.3, 183.5, 193, 95.8, 
223.7, 223.7, 227.1, 89.9, 98.4, 100)

#This is Negative binomial function:  
#PNB(x)= (gamma(x+k)/(gamma(k)*factorial(x)))*
#        ((mu*V/(k+mu*V))^x)*
#        ((k+mu*V)/k)^(-k)

#k and mu are the parameters to be optimized.

data<-data.frame(x,v)

NB<-function(par,data){
A<-gamma(x+par[1])/(gamma(par[1])*factorial(x))
B<-(par[2]*v/(par[1]+par[2]*v))^par[1]
C<-((par[1]+par[2]*v)/par[1])^(-par[1])
return(A*B*C)
}

best<-optim(par=c(1,1),data=data,NB,gr=NULL,method='BFGS',control=list(trace=12,REPORT=1))
```

it return following error:

```
Error in optim(par = c(1, 1), data = data, NB, gr = NULL, method = "BFGS",  : 
  objective function in optim evaluates to length 52 not 1
```

I also used *fitdistr* as follows but it only fits on x without considering the samples volume (v).

```
> fitdistr (x,"negative binomial")
     size         mu    
  1.3078442   0.5577050 
 (1.1107484) (0.1236888)
```

this mu is independent of v and I think is not correct.

Comment: `library(MASS)` has `fitdistr` function for this purpose (uses Maximum Likelihood method).

Comment: You might want to use glm.nb from MASS package.

Comment: It seems your optimization function is not written correctly. Try `NB(c(1, 1), data)` - it does not return a scalar.